# WhatsApp Calling Recording

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have an android phone (Samsung Galaxy S6). Does WhatApp Record Incoming Voice Phone Calls Automatically ?

In my call info log I see incoming, the length of time and a storage amount (40MB or so).

Can I access this incoming voice call recording ?

If WhatsApp doesnt record incoming or outgoing calls, how can I record them myself ?

Answer (score 2):

No whatsapp calls are end to end encrypted and it doesn't record calls.

You can use [Whatsapp call recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sparklingapps.callrecorder&hl=en&gl=US) to record calls. Remember to disable internet access of the app for more privacy :)

Comment: So what is the MB value beside your phone call in the phone call log mean ?  Is that stored somewhere ?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Here is an example screenshot: https://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-How-do-I-check-a-WhatsApp-call-duration.

Comment: See the MB value beside the call duration ?

Comment: @user4434 it's internet data used during call.

Comment: yeah it's the mobile data used.. during the call.. As @IrfanLatif already said :)

Comment: It's generally less like 400kb per minute(as i've read)  The 40mb (as you mentioned) is because it was a video call maybe or you talked tooooo long..

Comment: Is there a good app that records whatsapp calls that works and doesnt crash for samsung galaxy ?

Comment: yeah i suggested that in the answer